# Iterate over maps in cython

Tags: cython

I would like iterate over c++ maps in cython. How to do that? I have tried it.first but it says **compilation error iterator has no attribute first**.

Code I tried:

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc
....
cdef map[long,long].iterator it
....
it=cllasy.iswrong_class.begin()
while it!=cllasy.iswrong_class.end():
    print ("wd",it.first,it.second)
    inc(it)
```

Comment: Please share your code - it makes the question much easier to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython - iterate through map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686143/cython-iterate-through-map)

Comment: I've suggested a duplicate - I know this question was asked first so it isn't a judgement on this question