# Cython - iterate through map

Tags: python, cython

I was wondering if this was possible to iterate through a map directly in `Cython` code, *ie,* in the `.pyx`.
Here is my example:

```
import cython
cimport cython
from licpp.map import map as mapcpp

def it_through_map(dict mymap_of_int_int):
  # python dict to map
  cdef mapcpp[int,int] mymap_in = mymap_of_int_int
  cdef mapcpp[int,int].iterator it = mymap_in.begin()

  while(it != mymap.end()):
    # let's pretend here I just want to print the key and the value
    print(it.first) # Not working
    print(it.second) # Not working
    it ++ # Not working
```

This does not compile: `Object of type 'iterator' has no attribute 'first'`

I used map container in cpp before but for this code, I am trying to stick to cython/python, is it possible here?.

**Resolved by DavidW**
Here is an working version of the code, following DavidW answer:

```
import cython
cimport cython
from licpp.map import map as mapcpp
from cython.operator import dereference, postincrement

def it_through_map(dict mymap_of_int_int):
  # python dict to map
  cdef mapcpp[int,int] mymap_in = mymap_of_int_int
  cdef mapcpp[int,int].iterator it = mymap_in.begin()

  while(it != mymap.end()):
    # let's pretend here I just want to print the key and the value
    print(dereference(it).first) # print the key        
    print(dereference(it).second) # print the associated value
    postincrement(it) # Increment the iterator to the net element
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The map iterator doesn't have elements `first` and `second`. Instead it has a `operator*` which returns a `pair` reference. In C++ you can use `it->first` to do this in one go, but that syntax doesn't work in Cython (and it isn't intelligent enough to decide to use `->` instead of `.` itself in this case).

Instead you use [`cython.operator.dereference`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#c-operators-not-compatible-with-python-syntax):

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference

# ...

print(dereference(it).first)
```

Similarly, `it++` can be done with `cython.operator.postincrement`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It is working, I am editing the post.